# Seeking to create columns of tweets with just the tokens

Tags: token, tweets, quanteda

This is my dataframe. I am hoping to create a column called tokens that has the tokens for each tweet in the rows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VFU5.png)

I tried making the tokens a tibble.

Comment: I am confuse you looking for full_text (2nd column) from doc_id(1st column)? But you have already the full_text column in dataframe. Can you explain more detail what is your looking for and what means "tibble"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.